# Access multiple levels of many to many children with Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a table structure with several many to many joins.

```
nodes -< node_template >- templates -< placeholder_template >- placeholder
```

I have my node, template, and placeholder models setup with `belongsToMany` methods to link the main tables through the join tables.

e.g.

```
public function byFileMakerIdWithTemplates($id){
    return $this->node->with('templates')->where('internal_id', '=', $id)->firstOrFail();
}
```

Is there a way of selecting multiple levels of child nodes using eloquent?

I.e., Is there a way that I can query for a specific `node` record and get the `template` child records AND the template's `placeholder` records? Something like:

```
public function byFileMakerIdWithTemplates($id){
    return $this->node->with('templates')->with('placeholders')->where('internal_id', '=', $id)->firstOrFail();
}
```

I know I could use the `DB` facade to write you the mysql query I would need to grab all of the data using `JOIN` clauses or write the code to find the node with all of it's templates and then foreach through each template to find the placeholders, but if there was a way to grab it all cleanly in a multidimensional array it would be fantastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can eager load deeply nested relationships by using the `.` dot syntax:

```
with('relationA.relationB');
```

So you would write:

```
public function byFileMakerIdWithTemplates($id){
    return $this->node->with('templates.placeholders')->where('internal_id', '=', $id)->firstOrFail();
}
```

Comment: Perfect, that did the job. Thanks for the point in the right direction!

Comment: Hi sir, i just need a small assist, http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67732/discussion-between-biz-dev-b-and-lukasgeiter i will delete this comment now

Comment: @lukasgeiter You don't need to specify each level of nesting separately in this case, so simply `with('relation.nested.anotherLevel')`.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk Even better!